# The wire frame from a Plot3D gives a jumbled mess for a wire frame

Tags: plotting, functions

Some time ago I found a post that turned the triangles of a mesh into polygons. I have spent 2 hours looking for that post and can not find it.

The problem: Plotting

```
p = Plot3D[x^2+y^2,{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}];(*code by Jens*)
With[{zScale = .05},
Export["squishedPlot.wrl", 
p /. Graphics3D[gr_, opts___] :> 
Graphics3D[
 GeometricTransformation[gr, ScalingTransform[{1, 1, zScale}]], 
 opts]]
]
```

[image]

Produces a bad mesh/wire frame. I can Import this into Blender and it is not what MMA plots at all.
[image]
As you can see, towards the base, you get extra lines, when rendered in Blender, it looks bad. Having all polygons and no triangles is a must for 3d modeling.

The image below was solely created in Blender, but it has a much better wire frame. Yes it has triangles but I think it is just the way MMA imports the file.

Solution: I need a function to produce a wire frame of a plot that will produce a polygon and not Triangles.

[image]

Comment: You can visualize the exported triangles directly in Mathematica if you add `Mesh -> All` to the `Plot3D` command. The smaller triangles are created by recursive refinement, you can turn it off using `MaxRecursion -> 0` and then you will get something closer to your desired output.

Comment: @Rahul It works perfectly, Thank you sir!